# Theme.AppCompat on Fragment class

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

I have a fragment class that extended from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. now in it's layout I have added :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_chat_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/loaded_items"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txv_count_notify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#0000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="32546874"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

but i got this error and nothing is showing in layout:

```
Select Theme.AppCompat or a descendant in the theme selector
```

this is my styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I am using fragment and I do not want to use of **Activity** and extend from **AppCompatActivity**. what is your suggestion?

Comment: Ever got an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in your `@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay` and `@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay`. Probably the doesn't inherit AppCompat themes. `parent="..."` tag may override in-file inherit using `AppTheme.<child_theme_name>`

Have you searched for the same problems before?

Comment: what do you mean? how could i fix it?this is in manifest file: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Comment: Please give styles.xml for @style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay and @style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay

Comment: this is my whole styles.xml contains:`<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
`

Comment: Where is defined your @style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay? Can you provide its definition?

Comment: this is default configuration.should i declare?

Comment: ok, just remove app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" and android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" from your xml.

Comment: Well, check the stacktrace. One of your themes doesn't inherits from AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```